# Need find finding sample standard deviation from histogram

Tags: statistics

[image]

a) Hi, I need help with this question in the image. I know that the sample median is 37.7 as the data is heavily skewed to the right. But I don't know what numbers to assign to sample mean and sample standard deviation. How can I figure this out?

b) The distribution is bimodal and skewed to the right. But I don't know how to use this info to help me figure out what to assign to sample standard deviation and sample mean

Thank You

Comment: I wouldn't say your histogram is 'bimodal' just because one histogram happens to be a bit higher by chance than its neighbors. You're right about the right-skewness, which will tend to make the mean larger than the median. // If your text has formulas for finding sample mean and SD from data in 'frequency & value` format, take a look at that. My approximate  method assumes values are centers of histogram bars.

Comment: Doesn't a second "peak" in a histogram indicate bimodal distribution however? If it's not bimodal what would you say that it is? Symmetric doesn't seem right to use in this case.

Comment: And Unimodal doesn't seem right either

Comment: If you make another histogram with slightly different bins, then what you imagine to be a second mode could easily disappear. Various textbooks have different definitions of sample modes, Some make more sense than others. If your text has a straightforward definition of sample mode, then use it (at least while you're still in the course). // Notice that the posted histogram of my simulated sample also has "uneven" histogram bars in the right tail. In that case we know the population has the unimodal exponential dist'n. // See Addendum to my Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Estimating Sample Mean and SD from Histogram**

***Method:***

A frequently used approach is to pretend that all observations in a histogram bin fall at the center of the bin. Centers are:
$(m_1 = 30, m_2 = 50, \dots, m_8 = 170).$

Then try to read bin frequencies $f_1, \dots, f_8$
from the vertical scale of the histogram.
Also, check that $n = \sum_{i=1}^8 f_i = 90,$ as
claimed in the header.

A reasonable estimate of the sample mean is
$$\bar X \approx \frac 1 n\sum_{i=1}^8 f_im_i.$$

And the sample variance is estimated as

$$S_x^2 \approx \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^8 f_i(m_i - \bar X)^2.$$

Take the square root to estimate the sample SD.

***Example:*** Suppose we have the sample of $n = 90$
observations from $\mathsf{Exp}(\mathrm{rate}=0.02),$
an exponential distribution with mean $\mu = 50$ and
standard deviation $\sigma = 50,$ as sampled in R
below:

```
set.seed(919)
x = rexp(90, 0.02)
set.seed(919)
summary(x);  sd(x)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
  0.4624  14.2365  25.9412  44.1609  54.6213 173.0243 
[1] 43.02516  # sample SD

cp = seq(0,180, by=20);  cp  # cut points for histogram
 [1]   0  20  40  60  80 100 120 140 160 180
hist(x, br = cp, ylim=c(0,40), label=T)
```

[image]

Estimate sample mean `a` and standard deviation `s` from
the histogram:

```
m = seq(10, 170, by=20)
f = c(32,23,14,4,3,6,4,2,2)  # copied from histogram
sum(f)
[1] 90
a = sum(f*m)/90;  a
[1] 45.33333             # aprx 44.16
v = sum(f*(m-a)^2)/89; v
[1] 1807.191
s = sqrt(v);  s
[1] 42.51107             # aprx 43.03
```

Notice that in order to match roughly with your problem,
my histogram required nine bins. The approximations
from the histogram are not far from the exact computations for the data.

***Addendum*** on "modes" in histograms. According to your view on modes, I guess the histogram below must have **several** modes. How many would you say? Three? Four?

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused. If s = 42.51, mean is 45.33, and median is 25, what do I assign the number 67.3 to? None of the numbers above are even close to 67.3. Also I'm not sure if this is what you're saying but does this mean that the correct answer is s = 37.7, median is 57.5 and mean is 67.3. I got these numbers as 42.51 (as you calculated above and I got a similar approximation using the formula in my book) is pretty close to 37.7 so I assigned s to 37.7, then median must be 57.5 as median is smaller then mean in a right-skewed distribution. So mean must be 67.3, is my reasoning correct here?

Comment: Please notice that my example is not exactly the same as your problem. I'm **illustrating** my formulas which you need to use to work your problem. My data are from exponential distn with $\mu = \sigma = 50$ and median about 35. So sample mean and SD and median not too far from pop values for such a small sample. I suspect your data may be 'delayed' exponential with mean and median (not SD) somewhat inflated. But you'll have to compute the formulas to find out.